# Which Azure service should I use for SignalR websocket?

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr

I am completely new to using Azure so I could use a little advice.  Here is my scenario.  I need to develop an application that was originally thought to be a windows service but is now to be deployed to Azure.  The app is a scheduling application that reads from a DB and calls a couple of different APIs when it's time to either start or stop an event.  The DB will be stored in Azure as well.

Initially, this sounds like a WebJob, but the issue is I also need for the app to be both host and client for a SignalR WebSocket.  The intent of this is to have two instances communicate with each other and a backup self-promote if it loses communication with the primary.  My understanding is that WebJobs don't support things like WebSockets.

Is there an Azure service that would work well for this.  I can use a virtual machine but would like to avoid it if possible.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this one:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/

Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview

Sample code:
https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples